# How to put variable in Where() method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase

Sorry for this question, because I'm a newbie in this field. So, I currently working with Firebase Firestore for my website, where the usual way to getting documents from Firebase is working perfectly. But, when I made a search feature, I must filter the document from Firebase by `where('field name in Firebase','equations like "=", ">",">=", etc.', 'parameter')`. My problem is I want to put a value from the search-bar which I called `source`. After converting the value of `source` with `toLowerCase()`, I want to assign the variable `source` into the parameter inside the `where()` functions. But, it doesn't work well, because in some tutorials I've watched, they used literally string data type and put it inside the `where()` parameter. Can anyone help me solve this problem? By the way, I've tried to input some `string` inside the parameter and it works well. I'll leave the data remains in Firebase, in case you want to mess with it. Thank you.

```js
target1.addEventListener('search', search);
function search(){
    source = target1.value;
    source = source.toLowerCase();
    db.collection('Product').where('name','>=', 'source').where('name','<=', 'source' + '\uf8ff').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
    let changes = snapshot.docChanges();
    changes.forEach(change =>{
        if (change.type == 'added'){
            insertDoc(change.doc);
        }
        else if (change.type == 'removed'){
            let box = docTarget.querySelector('[data-id=' + change.doc.id +']');
            docTarget.removeChild(box); 
        }
    })
})
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'Product Sans';
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-style: normal;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/productsans/v5/HYvgU2fE2nRJvZ5JFAumwegdm0LZdjqr5-oayXSOefg.woff2), format('woff2');
    max-width: 360px;
    height: auto;

}

body{
    background-color: white;
    background-size: cover;
    max-height: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.big-container{
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    width: 360px;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}


.arc{
    position: relative;
    background-color:#E67E22;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    width: 360px;
    height: 150px;;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 25px 25px;
    transform: translate(0,-5px);
    z-index: 1;
}

.title{
    font-size: 32px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 27px;
}

.cancel{
    position: relative;
    top:-6px;
    left: 300px;
    z-index: -10;
}

.sorter{
    position: relative;
    top:-6px;
    left:15px;
}

input{
    position: relative;
    width: 312px;
    height: 35px;
    left: -24px;
    top: 47px;
    border:2px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #E67E22;
    outline: none;
    padding-top: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    transition: 0.5s;
    z-index: 10;
}

::placeholder{
    color: white;
}

#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 360px;
    min-height: 100px;
    height: auto;
    left: 0px;
    top: 145px;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 12.5px;
    padding: 12px;
    padding-top: 22px;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,157px);
    grid-auto-rows: 95px;
    grid-column-gap: 23px;
    grid-row-gap: 16px;

}

.box{
    width: 157px;
    min-height: 95px;
    max-height: auto;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-radius: 12.5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.title-box{
    position: relative;
    top: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Product Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    color: #E67E22;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.tc-1{
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 33px;
    font-family: Product Sans Light;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    color: #000000;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.tc-2{
    position: relative;
    top: 26px;
    left: 14px;
    font-family: Product Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.00em;
    color: #000000;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.tc-3{
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
    left: 110px;
    font-family: Product Sans Light;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    color: #000000;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.tc-4{
    position: relative;
    top: -6px;
    left: 88px;
    font-family: Product Sans;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0.00em;
    color: #000000;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.box:hover{
    background: #E67E22;
    transition: ease-in-out 0.5s;
    color: white;
}

.box:hover h4, 
.box:hover p{
    color: white;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

h2{
    width: 157px;
    min-height: 95px;
    max-height: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 2px;
    visibility: visible;
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
}

.closer{
    visibility: visible;
    position: relative;
    top: -100px;
    left: 135px;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <title>SDE Stock | Cari</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
            https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.14.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="big-container">
        <span class="navbar">
                <div class="arc">
                    <p class="title">Cari produk</p>
                    <img src="Group 2.svg" alt="" class="cancel">
                    <img src="menu 1.svg" alt="" class="sorter">
                    <input type="search" class="searcher">
                </div>
        </span>
        <div id="wrapper">
                <!-- <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div class="box"></div>
                <div id="last-element" class="important"></div> -->
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyARW1T5mnayv7XVsHnfP_uc0jO-ck11ykw",
            authDomain: "sde-sale-stock.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://sde-sale-stock.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "sde-sale-stock",
            storageBucket: "sde-sale-stock.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "247739189879",
            appId: "1:247739189879:web:0f809640941c5d3e341472",
            measurementId: "G-VS6QCRD18K"
        };
        // Initialize Firebase
        firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
        firebase.analytics();
        const db = firebase.firestore();

    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `source` is a variable, then you need to do the following:

```
source = target1.value;
source = source.toLowerCase();
db.collection('Product').where('name','>=', source).where('name','<=', source + '\uf8ff').onSnapshot(snapshot =>{
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! But I think I have figured out the problem is the value of document from Firebase isn't in lowercase, because it's case sensitive, it will affect. Anyway, your answer is work well with both data is lowercase. Thanks